# An issue with deploying an asp.net core 3.1 application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, deployment

I have recently deployed an asp.net core 3.1 application to the IIS 10I I am using Windows Server 2016). I can have access to it on the web server and also on the other computers in the company's domain but I can not have any access to it outside the company's domain and I get the message of 'This site can't be reached'. I am using http, the IP address of the web server with port 80. The firewalls on the web server is off. What should I do to solve this issue? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: At the end, you'll have to ask the company's admin. It seems to be no iis or asp core issue but a network issue. We can only guess: If the server is inside a company network you may have an internal IP (only available in their network). To be able to access a system from the internet, you need a public IP and this public IP must be routed to the correct server. A common alternative is to use VPN to become "part of the internal company network" even if you're outside the company.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should add to my issue that I added an Inbound rule for port 81 and firewall is off too. This IP address is actually the web server's IP address, but again it didn't work outside the network. There is another .net app running in this web server too, accessible outside the network(Of course, it has an unassigned IP and hostname which it didn't work for my asp.net core app). So do you think in this context having a public IP address can be useful?

Comment: Setting up a network can be quite complex and I don't know anything about the setup in your case. You'll have to ask an administrator who knows the setup.

Comment: i suggest you could try to ping your server's IP address by using tcp ping firstly to make sure you could access the IP from network. If you couldn't access the server by using TCP ping, that means  there is something wrong with your IP address or your network. Then You should ask your network IT to tell you the right public address.